# How to use types in javascript without typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have googled this question but found the answers to be a bit confusing. I recently got employed to be a nodejs developer. I have been working as a java developer for the last few years. Im a little bit worried about writing nodejs and not having types. But at the same time I want to write code in the same way that everybody else in the team is doing it, so I dont want to use typescript, and at the same time I dont want to be that guy that comes into a new team and is like trying to get everybody to change to their thing. So my question is. Is there a way to write nodejs just so I get types. Like if I create a javascript class

```
function Apple (type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.color = "red";
    this.getInfo = getAppleInfo;
}
```

And then I use it

```
var apple = new Apple('macintosh');
apple.color = "reddish";
alert(apple.getInfo());
```

When I write 'apple.' I would like Webstorm or Atom to know that there is a type, color, and getInfo() function available. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: what returns `getInfo` usually in typescript?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you could setup a TypeScript to check your JavaScript files without coding in TypeScript?

Comment: I'm pretty sure WebStorm is smart enough to do this for you, but that's IDE specific.

Comment: What's the problem with using TypeScript? If you feel more comfortable with it then just use it. The compiled output will still be JavaScript. The only difference: some ts files in your version control

Comment: Thanks! @andreas the problem is nobody else is using it and I want to do things like everybody else when it comes to checking in code. So if I check in ts files then it'll be like wtf moment on my first day. I'd like to handle it at the ide level or some other covert local cheat... I think I'll check to see if web storm does it automatically if not I might configure a typescript compiler just for type checking.... Idunno! But thanks for the input!

Comment: New guys bring new stuff. Maybe it's worth the "risk". As long as you get the job done in time there should not be any problem with a more robust way of coding. jm2c :D